# Is Presentation state is a new image?

Tags: dicom

When a presentation state has created for a image will it creates a new image? If it creates a new image then adding a PS should increase the image count by +1?

Comment: Can you elaborate more by editing the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new presentation state object should be created in it's own series within the same study as the image(s) being referenced.
What "image count" are you referring to? If you are referring to (0020,1208) VR=IS Number of Study Related Instances or (0020,1209) VR=IS Number of Series Related Instances, then yes, since this is a new instance, it affects instance related counts.